# Can Tibco HTTP receiver perform 1 PORT and many Operations?

Tags: tibco

Can Tibco BW HTTP receiver perform ONE PORT and many Operations like service activity did???

If yes, how to configure???
Please advice.

Thanks so much and good weekends.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to have transitions from your HTTP Receiver Process Starter to Call Process Activities, that invoke each of your operations. In each transition, set the condition type to success with condition and set the XPath appropriately.

Answer (score -1):

No its not possible using BW HTTP, For multiple operations you must use service activity.